IntelliJ change the scrollbar to be like Mac scrollbar but on Windows
Is there any reference for IntelliJ IDE to create a plugin to change the ugly scrollbar of Windows to be like Mac styled scrollbar, set border radius, width and height, color, etc?
Got a round around the docs, but it keeps changing no even any git repositories found to just check the code.

There are no extension points to modify the scrollbar. The only way is using your custom build of IDEA community edition, so you can modify IDEA code.
